# How do i Fix this django.db.utils.DatabaseError

Tags: django, database, djongo

How do i fix Django Database error. I'm using MongoDB with Djongo.

Everything was working fine until recently. When it tested it after some days, it doesnt work. i am able to use get method without error, but when i request a post mehtod , i get this django.db.utils.DatabaseError.

Internal Server Error: /category
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
self.result = Query(
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in **init**
self._query = self.parse()
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 876, in parse
raise e
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 857, in parse
return handler(self, statement)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 928, in _insert
query = InsertQuery(self, self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 340, in **init**
super().**init**(*args)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in **init**
self.parse()
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 410, in parse
self._fill_values(statement)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 368, in _fill_values
raise SQLDecodeError
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

```
    Keyword: None
    Sub SQL: None
    FAILED SQL: ('INSERT INTO "RentApp_category" ("type") VALUES (%(0)s)',)
    Params: (['Wardrobes'],)
    Version: 1.3.6
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/Desktop/Django/RentFlux/RentApp/views.py", line 63, in post
serializer.save()
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 962, in create
instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 658, in create
obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
self.save_base(
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 877, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1020, in _save_table
results = self._do_insert(
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert
return manager._insert(
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/sangeethsivan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
[19/Feb/2024 17:21:24] "POST /category HTTP/1.1" 500 221534

I wanted a successful post method, as the same as worked before. I dont know what has changed, as I kept the code unedited.